# pythonの変数代入時の二重イコールの意味

Tags: python, python3

変数の代入時に使用されている。以下のコードが分かりません。条件分岐になっているのでしょうか？

```
need_size = (row[1] == 'onesize')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

右辺の計算結果を代入してるだけかと思います。
つまりneed_sizeはbool型になるかと。

pythonのversionが少し古いですが以下実行結果になります。
[image: 画像]

あくまで返り値のある式である限り代入はできますのでこんなこともできます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

pythonの実行環境が整ってあるようであればシェル上で`python`を実行すれば対話モードで簡単にpythonコードを実行できますので、そちらで検証してくださればと思います！

[対話モードとは](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode)

Comment: 比較して一致する場合は左辺にtrueが代入されると言う事でしょうか？

Comment: そうです！回答を補足しましたのでご確認ください！

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

二重イコール`==`は「比較演算子」と言って、左辺と右辺を比較して一致すれば`True`、違っていれば`False`と言うbool型の値を返す演算子です。
このような比較演算子（他にも `!=`, `>`, `<`, `in` なども文法的にはこの二重イコールの仲間です）を使った式は条件分岐などでよく見かける式ですが、その式の中身はbool型の値（`True`か`False`）になっていて、条件分岐以外にも今回のような使い方もできるんですね。

ご質問のコード

```
need_size = (row[1] == 'onesize')
```

の場合、

（１）`row[1]`の値が`'onesize'`と一致していれば、変数`need_size`には`True`が代入される
（２）`row[1]`の値が`'onesize'`と違っていれば、変数`need_size`には`False`が代入される

このどちらかの操作が行われていることになります。

既に上記のご回答にてご理解されているようなので蛇足になってしまったかもしれませんが、よければ参考にしていただけたらと思います！